# Android Room Live Data Listener makes App crash

Tags: android, observers, android-room, android-livedata

I implemented a room database for my android app. It fills the databse asynchronously with a test item, which seems to work so far. Now I want to implement a listener that dynamically updates the UI if the data changes. But my listener makes the app crash on startup. This is my listener in the activity:

```
    LiveData<List<Cat>> CatLiveData = Manager.getDB().getCatDAO().getCats();
    CatLiveData. observe(this, new Observer<List<Cat>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Cat> Cats) {
            //Update your UI here.
            binding.myControl.setText(Cats.get(0).getsName().toString());
        }
    });
```

It is supposed to fetch the very first element of the Cats-list and return its name property. The myControl is supposed to show this property. Check for null does not solve the crash.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
This is the LOgCat

01-23 22:18:00.863 9633-9633/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-23 22:18:00.931 9633-9640/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-23 22:18:00.931 9633-9640/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
01-23 22:18:01.377 9633-9633/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /mnt/expand/27c5fc5f-9c8e-4173-8379-f18e8d4cf183/app/com.example.erik.test-1/lib/arm
01-23 22:18:01.411 9633-9633/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-23 22:18:01.612 9633-9633/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-23 22:18:02.213 9633-9652/com.example.erik.test I/Adreno-EGL: : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (I389a668de0)
                                                                 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.28.00.04
                                                                 Build Date: 10/24/15 Sat
                                                                 Local Branch: mybranch15621148
                                                                 Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.3_rb1.3
                                                                 Local Patches: NONE
                                                                 Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
01-23 22:18:02.217 9633-9652/com.example.erik.test I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-23 22:18:02.217 9633-9652/com.example.erik.test D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-23 22:18:02.267 9633-9633/com.example.erik.test D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-23 22:18:02.268 9633-9633/com.example.erik.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.erik.test, PID: 9633
                                                                     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method iteratorWithAdditions()Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$ListIterator; in class Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap' appears in /mnt/expand/27c5fc5f-9c8e-4173-8379-f18e8d4cf183/app/com.example.erik.test-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                         at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:145)
                                                                         at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:293)
                                                                         at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$2.run(LiveData.java:108)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Comment: "But my listener makes the app crash on startup" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: post your log cat

Comment: Ok, I added. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

By now, I have rebuilt the app from sratch - I never found the exact reason it did not work. Most likely, the chaotic structure had many beginner's flaws. For a very good and easy manual on Room Databases that helped me fix the issues, I can recommend this Codelab:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0